# Make value of a parameter the column name without dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, ssms

Is there a way to name a column the value of what's in a parameter, without using dynamic SQL?

I need to somehow output the value of what is in the `@input` parameter as the name of the column in the SQL statement. I need to avoid using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10)=' Person '; 

SELECT count(*) AS  @input + ' Open Data'    
FROM #Accounts a
JOIN dbo.FileFeed t On t.ID = a.AccountID     
GROUP BY a.accountid
```

Comment: Why not handle it directly in the client side, assigning the query some internal name and the displaying it nicely in whatever UI you're using?

Comment: Oh I completely agree that the client side should be handling the naming convention but I'm inheriting old code. Which means numerous things are utilizing this code and not just my app and Always difficult trying to track down everything.

Comment: Is the value in the variable open-ended input or are there a limited number of values that it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10) = ' Person '; 

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT count(*) AS  [@Input Open Data]    
FROM #Accounts a JOIN
     dbo.FileFeed t
     On t.ID = a.AccountID     
GROUP BY a.accountid';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@Input', @Input);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

However, I don't really think this is a good idea.  If you need to rename a column, do it in the application code.

Comment: I completely agree the application should be handing the naming convention but it stinks when you inherit something written a long time ago and try to track down everything that is calling it.

Answer (score 3):

One **ugly way**, without `Dynamic-SQL` is using temporary table and rename column:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10) = ' Person '; 
DECLARE @new_name VARCHAR(100) = @input + ' Open Data';

SELECT [rename_me] = COUNT(*)
INTO #temp    
FROM #Accounts a
JOIN dbo.FileFeed t On t.ID = a.AccountID     
GROUP BY a.accountid;

EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#temp.rename_me', @new_name, 'COLUMN';

SELECT * 
FROM #temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Databases use a process similar to compiling to turn your query into an execution plan. Part of this process involves determining whether the user running the query has permissions to access the tables and columns used by the query. If those tables and columns are not determined until execution time, the compilation step can't finish. It seems strange, but the same thing applies to the result set.

Dynamic SQL (which creates a new query, with a new compilation step where the tables and column names are known up front) will be the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No".  Dynamic SQL, by definition, means that the code can alter itself.  The only alternative to Dynamic SQL is Hard-Coded SQL, which is when you specifically write every piece of it yourself.

You're asking if you can change a field name based on a variable, which can only be done with Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you rename the columns in the application, this is the way i would do it.

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10)=' Person '; 
Declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql'SELECT count(*) as ['+ @input +' Open Data]
FROM #Accounts a
JOIN dbo.FileFeed t On t.ID = a.AccountID     
GROUP BY a.accountid';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

*IF* it is the case that the values of what can be in the `@input` variable / parameter are limited (i.e. not open-ended user input or something of that nature), then you can do this without DynamicSQL. You just need to have multiple copies of the query in this Stored Procedure, each being exactly the same except for the alias of the column, and pick the one you want based on the value of the variable. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10)=' Person '; 

IF (@input = 'Person')
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Person Open Data]
  FROM #Accounts a
  JOIN dbo.FileFeed t
    ON t.ID = a.AccountID     
  GROUP BY a.accountid;
END;

IF (@input = 'Account')
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Account Open Data]
  FROM #Accounts a
  JOIN dbo.FileFeed t
    ON t.ID = a.AccountID     
  GROUP BY a.accountid;
END;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a later version of SQL Server then you might look at this option:

```
EXEC <stored_procedure> WITH RESULT SETS (...)
```

I imagine you're already using a stored procedure. This way you'd at least be able to keep the main logic completely static in a second procedure and just interface to a procedure with the dynamic `exec` call to accomplish the renaming of column(s).